# ¿Como llenar un input de acuerdo al valor de otro? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario en mi pagina web en el cual necesito que cuando un usuario ingrese un Código en un input en otro input se auto complete el Nombre.
Tengo el codigo que muestro a continuación, pero no hace nada.
Tengo dos tablas:
TablaCodigos:
Codigo_p varchar 
...

TablaPersonas
Codigo_p varchar 
Nombre varchar 
...

Mi script

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Codigo_p").change(function () {
$.getJSON("/Solicitud/GetPersona?Codigo_p=" + $("#Codigo_p").val(), function (result) 
{
            var select = $("#nombreP");
            select.empty();
            $.each(result, function (index, itemData) {
            select.append($({
            value: itemData.Nombre
            }));
        });
    });
 }
</script>
```

Mi controlador

```html
public JsonResult GetPersona(string Codigo_p)
{
  bd.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  TablaPersonas nom_p = bd.TablaPersonas.Where(x => x.Codigo_p == Codigo_p).Single();
  return Json(nom_p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
<div class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary subtitulo">Persona:</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreP" name="nombreP" placeholder="Nombre" readonly="" >
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque tienes dos veces `Codigo_pCodigo_p` en el `where`?

Comment: Fue error al copiar, gracias por la observacion @alanfcm

Comment: Que error te sale en javascript?

Comment: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of null @alanfcm

Comment: Que te sale en consola cuando haces `console.log(results)` antes del `each`?

Comment: si hago eso si me trae el json con los datos, pero sigue marcando el error de la imagen

Comment: Podrias poner el screenshot de lo que sale en consola?

Comment: Tu elemento nombreP es un input-text o un select-option?

Comment: es un input type="text" @KodiakMx

Comment: Y porque le haces un append? que no debería de ser un $("#nombreP").text(itemData.nombre) ?

Comment: Tu controlador regresa una lista? por qué le pones un Single()?

Comment: Tu controlador regresa un elemento nada más? Por qué hace un foreach a un elemento simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No necesitas un bucle para iterar los resultados porque la respuesta es simplemente un objeto.  Para setear el valor puedes igualar el valor del input a la propiedad que quieres asi:

```
$.getJSON("/Solicitud/GetPersona?Codigo_p=" + $("#Codigo_p").val(), function (result) 
{
            var select = $("#nombreP");
            select.empty();
            select.val(result.Nombre);                
        });
    });
 }
```

O para simplificar tu codigo, la siguiente linea es equivalente:

```
$("#nombreP").val(result.Nombre);
```

Comment: En este caso, de los varios que leo entre lineas, tampoco es necesario el empty()

Answer (score 3):

De entrada veo que al select lo vacias antes de rellenar el otro input

```
var select = $("#nombreP");
select.empty();
```

Lo que yo haría es algo así

```
$("#Codigo_p").change(function(){
      var select = $("#nombreP");
      $('#id_input_a_rellenar').val(select);
});
```

Ojala te sirva!

Comment: Hola, asi como tal no me funciona porque ya no trae el valor del controlador, y id_input_a_rellenar debe ser nombreP, nose si me explico